# Combine two lists alternatively

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, python-zip

I am doing a simple list comprehension: combine two lists in alternative order and make another list.

```
big_list = [i,j for i,j in zip(['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],['2022-01-31','2022-02-28'])]
```

Expected output:

```
['2022-01-01','2022-01-31','2022-02-01','2022-02-28']
```

Present output:

```
Cell In[35], line 1
    [i,j for i,j in zip(['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],['2022-01-31','2022-02-28'])]
     ^
SyntaxError: did you forget parentheses around the comprehension target?
```

Comment: Not the full answer, but doing what the error message suggests: `big_list = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],['2022-01-31','2022-02-28'])` gets rid of the syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a nested comprehension to pull the items out of the zipped tuples:

```
big_list = [
    i
    for t in zip(
        ['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],
        ['2022-01-31','2022-02-28']
    )
    for i in t
]
```

Comment: I would recommend this one is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can unnest from zip:

```
big_list = [
item 
for s in 
zip(['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],['2022-01-31','2022-02-28']) 
for item in s]

#output

['2022-01-01', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28']
```

---

One way is to use itertools:

```
import itertools
big_list = list(itertools.chain(*zip(['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],['2022-01-31','2022-02-28'])))

#output

['2022-01-01', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28']
```

**Edit:**

This will be very slow:

```
sum([list(x) for x in zip(['2022-01-01','2022-02-01'],['2022-01-31','2022-02-28'])],[])

#output

['2022-01-01', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28']
```

Answer (score 2):

A `zip`-free comprehension: alternated append.

```
l1 = ['2022-01-01','2022-02-01']
l2 = ['2022-01-31','2022-02-28']

l = [l1[i//2] if not i % 2 else l2[(i)//2] for i in range(min(len(l1), len(l2))*2)]
```

The `min` is used to ensure equally sized lists (as `zip` would do).

---

A `zip`-free functional approach. If lists of different sizes then a `zip`-like "politics" is applied.

```
from itertools import chain
# l1, l2 from above

l = list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x, y: (x, y), l1, l2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of it, because I'd actually use `zip` too:

```
list1 = ['2022-01-01','2022-02-01']
list2 = ['2022-01-31','2022-02-28']
big_list = [(list1, list2)[i%2][i//2] for i in range(2 * min(len(list1), len(list2)))]
```

Another version, using `itertools.cycle` to switch between 2 iterators over the two lists:

```
from itertools import cycle
big_list = [next(next(cy)) for cy in [cycle((iter(list1), iter(list2)))] for _ in range(2 * min(len(list1), len(list2)))]
```

Comment: nice way to jump around between the 2 lists with `i%2`... without the need of conditionals:)

Comment: Thanks; I tried another one with itertools.cycle and list iterators, but couldn't manage StopIteration correctly...

Comment: `cycle` was my 1st thought as well:) and thanks to your answer (and comment) here it is `[(list1, list2)[next(c)][i//2] for c in [it.cycle([0, 1])] for i in range(len(list1) + len(list2))]`

Comment: Nice one; and that just gave me what I needed to complete what I had in mind (cycling between 2 iterators over list1 and list2): see my updated answer :)

Comment: Another: `[next(it) for it in islice(cycle((iter(list1), iter(list2))), len(list1) + len(list2))]`. And since you rely on equal lengths anyway, you could just multiply one by 2.

Comment: And here's a tricky one: `list(map(next, cycle(map(iter, (list1, list2)))))`

Comment: @KellyBundy: I love the 2nd one (all the more since I verified it works for unbalanced lists). And about the lengths, I made myself the same comment, but resorted to laziness (aka: copy-paste :) ).

Comment: I love it, too, although that's partly because of the trickiness, as it's not quite obvious why it stops, so it's a bit of a puzzle. I've looked for a fitting question where I could post it, but all I find is people asking about *two* lists where simpler solutions exist...

Comment: @Kelly Bundy thanks for your comments:) I am going crazy at how to declare a variable in a comprehension, I read it in a "What's new"  in the doc... but I cannot find it any more. In my previous comment I did `c in [it.cycle([0, 1])]` but I don't if it is the right way. Do you anything about that?

Comment: @cards You mean [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations)?

Answer (score 1):

my code pairs corresponding elements from l1 and l2 using the `zip` function, and using `for` loop to combine each element with its pair

```py
l1 = ["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01"]
l2 = ["2022-01-31", "2022-02-28"]
zipped_lists = zip(l1, l2)
l3 = []
for list in zipped_lists:
    for date in list:
        l3.append(date)
print(l3)
# l3 = ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28']
```